# Can script using arcpy.mapping.MoveLayer() be made to run faster?

Tags: layers, arcpy

We're running ArcGIS 10.0 and using a python script to move layers, turn on the correct layers, zoom to the correct extent and export a pdf map.  The script normally takes 30 - 35 seconds to finish.  Moving layers takes the bulk of the processing time, usually 20 - 25 seconds using this code:

```
for y in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    move_lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer('Available Zips')
refLayer = move_lyr
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.name == zip_view:
        zip_move = lyr
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):       
    if lyr.name == zip_view:
        arcpy.mapping.MoveLayer(df, refLayer, zip_move, "BEFORE")
```

Is there a way to optimize this code to run faster?

Comment: I always place the result of long-running "generate a list of things" functions into a local variable, so that the effort doesn't need to be repeated.

Comment: Your edit would be better suited as an answer - it's perfectly ok to [answer your own question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  Changed the first "for" statement to this and this code now runs in 4 - 5 seconds:

```
for y in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if y.name == 'Available Zips':
        move_lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer('Available Zips')
```

Comment: Indentation issue!

Comment: Indention issue was only from copying and pasting into the message.  The actual solution was changing the for statement to include the additional if statement.